# How to support routes with and without language in URL in multilingual asp.net MVC website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, asp.net-mvc-routing

Trying to set up localization for my current mvc project.
I need to configure routing to support both urls: with and without language in it (eg. www.domain.com/en/about/contacts and www.domain.com/about/contact). Routes without lang in URL for default language.

I define routes this way

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Localization",
            url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{identifier}",
            defaults: new { lang = defaultLang, controller = "Home", action = "Index", identifier = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

but I can't meet one important requirement - my routes for default language should be "lang-less" in URL only till user specify needed language. Even if that language == defaultLanguage I need my routes includes it (lang) since it was selected by user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

The @Localization@ Route should look like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Localization",
            url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{identifier}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", identifier = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { lang = @"[a-z]{2}" }
        );
```

- No default value should be provided for lang
- It is required for me to add constraint for lang to help router recognize URLs with and without lang_s